# how to get previous month date range in php

Tags: php, date

I want to get the previous months date range with PHP. I have tried below function to get last month's date range.

```
$last_month_start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of last month'));
$last_month_end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last day of last month'));
echo $last_month_start_date.' - '.$last_month_end_date;
```

> Output: 2019-09-01 - 2019-09-30

but how can I get previous month's date range with PHP?

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I mean... that never changes... surely just 01/12/YEAR - 31/12/YEAR?

Comment: @treyBake no year never change only previous month range we want

Comment: Let post example input and output of date range

Comment: `I want to get last to last month's date range with PHP` <- the last month = 12, every year.. I'm just not sure why you're not using a date range and trying to dynamically work it out?

Comment: wait, are you wanting "last" (as in end of a series) or "previous" (the one before current)?

Comment: @treyBake actually I am showing results of last month and last to last moth results so that I want to show date range of result

Comment: @Mohini Please Check my answer it will give you your expected output.

Comment: while this is Oct then I want date rang like 2019-09-01 - 2019-09-30 last last to last month date range like 2019-08-01 - 2019-09-31 dynamically

Comment: @Mohini ah then you want **previous** not last

Comment: @treyBake yes exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Last to Last Month: If current month is `October` then below output gives first and last date of `August`

```
$last_to_last_start_date = $last_month_start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of last month -1 month')); 
// outout 2019-08-01

$last_to_last_end_date = $last_month_end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last day of last month -1 month')); 
// outout 2019-08-31

echo $last_to_last_start_date .' - '.$last_to_last_end_date ;
//Output : 2019-08-01 - 2019-08-31
```

Comment: No, I want  2019-08-01 - 2019-08-31

Comment: @Mohini Check Edited Answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a date-time object that is two months behind, then use a modifier of `first/last day of this month`. The `this month` modifier works on the month of the object, so if the object's date is in August, it will look for the first and last days of August.

This means that you can provide any value for `-2 months` (like  `February`, `-1 month`) and it will get the start and end-dates for that month.

```php
$start = new DateTime("-2 months");
$end = clone $start;
$start->modify("first day of this month");
$end->modify("last day of this month");
echo $start->format("Y-m-d")." - ".$end->format("Y-m-d");
```

In October 2019, this outputs,

> 2019-08-01 - 2019-08-31

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/udGtE